# AJAX Wordpress Site with Difficult URL settings

Tags: ajax, wordpress, url, themes

On this WordPress theme utilizing AJAX, proves to be difficult.  The developer of the theme cannot seem to find the issue or solution to it.

This site runs beautifully, if, and only IF, you type is this complete URL "http://www.geigerandwood.com/#!//"  if you type in the .com site alone, it will appear but will be disfunctional.

I have made attempts in 301 redirects, even creating a static page with a redirect but still no luck.  Is there something that I can add or change in the code to make this work properly?

FYI - it has been tested on the common web browsers on both OSX & Windows.

Here is a video of my presented issue. http://www.screenr.com/D1G8

Answer (score 0):

What theme do you use?

My quick examination of your page source code is that I only can find something related to the `#!//` is in here

```
<div id="contentBoxScroll">
<a id="closeButton" href="#!//"></a>
<div class="dragcontainer">
<div id="contentBoxScrollDragger" class="dragger">
<div class="scroll_up"></div>
<div class="scroll_down"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I assume it must be something inside the script from which that HTML is generated. I can say more since I can't see the full source.

Comment: Thanks for the look.  It's funny how the URL reacts and I have looked at this very spot.  the "closeButton" returns the window back to the home page gallery.  What I have been trying to do is automatically add the "#!//" at the end of the url when the site loads.

Comment: Also, the theme that I use is called "Right Now" and you can find it at [link](http://themeforest.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=right+now}

Comment: How about using .htaccess +OptionSymlink? Have you try that?

Comment: You're welcome for the link.
I thought about the .htaccess but don't know how to work it, but i'm not finding it in the root directory.

Comment: even better, I ran a search on it and not finding one.

Comment: what? The .htaccess? Haha, I have badly misspelled for it. It supposed to be Options +FollowSymlinks.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, nice long weekend.  I finally figured out the problem.  It was by following the developer's installation instructions that was the problem. Simple solution after all.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my post, it was well appreciated! :)